# Global Find and Replace in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter

I have multiple files open in tabs in TeXnicCenter, and I want to run a find-and-replace on every file simultaneously. Is there an easy way to do this?

Currently, I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in each file separately, and it is a pain to go through all of them. I'm not sure what exactly the "Find in Files..." option does, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I see *search **and** replace* in more than one file is not possible inside of TeXnicCenter *(searching inside of one file is, though)*. For that you need to change to another text editor. Searching only is possible over the menu “Search” and the menu entry “Find in Files” or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. It does exactly what it says: It lists the findings of a given pattern (“Find what”) inside of given files or file types (“In files/file types”), which are located in a selected folder/directory (“In” - you can select, that subfolders are searched, too, but it seems, it’s the default), no more, no less.

[image: TeXnicCenter: Find in Files dialogue]

Text editors for Windows where I know, that, what you want, is possible (I’m sure there are more):

- TeXworks, like TeXnicCenter an editor specialized to Tex files and co., part of both the important TeX distributions MiKTeX and TeXLive, but can also be downloaded from http://tug.org/texworks/
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
- [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/)
- [SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/)

(All off these with syntax highlighting for TeX files)

Answer (score 2):

`TeXnicCenter` shows you, as @Speravir said in his answer, a list of findings of a given pattern. You can click on each entry of this list and `TeXnicCenter` shows you the code in his great code window. If necceccary `TeXnicCenter` loads the `tex` file and shows the part with the serched pattern. There you can check and change the pattern, if you need.

I start at the end of this list and have so the advantage that the linenumers do not change when I change patterns (for example delete the pattern or insert more text).

Comment: Thanks for the addition. BTW I do so – going backwards, I mean.